# Splitting Large CSV files by Column

Tags: csv, split, large-files

I have a vey large (4gb) csv file. Cannot open in excel or in other editors. The number of lines (rows) is nearly 3,000 and the number of columns is nearly 320,000.

One solution is to split the original file into smaller ones and be able to open these small ones in Excel or other editors.

The second solution is to take the transpose of the original data then open it in the Excel.

I could not find a tool or script for transpose. I've found some scripts and free software for splitting but each of them splits the csv by row size.

Is there a way to split the original file into smaller ones that consist of max 15000 rows.

I tried to use:

import panda as pd
pd.read_csv(%file Path%).T.to_csv('%new File Path%,headre=false)

But it take ages to complete

Comment: `The second solution is to take the transpose` ... this won't change the size of the dataset at all, and it still might not open in Excel.  Even if it does, expect really slow performance.  What is your goal for working with this data?  Have you looked into using tools like R or Matlab?

Comment: The data set contains genetic info. Columns store SNPs as rs id and rows contain allel changes of that SNP. I want to filter those SNPs. Reduce the number of SNPs from 300,000 to 900

Answer (score 0):

In meanwhile I tired to use some python coding, but all of them failed because of the memory issues.

Trial version of the Delimit (http://www.delimitware.com/) handled the data perfectly.